# Vaadin Data Provider - Sorting with a backend using bean as parameter in a query

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

## Background

I'm trying to allow data in a Vaadin Grid to be sortable. The data is retrieved from a backend using REST calls. The bean types look something like this:

```java
public class Event {

  private Type type;
  private LocalDateTime latest;

  //... getters, setters, etc.
}
```

```java
public class Type {
  private String name;
  private String callCode;  

  //... getters, setters, etc. 
}
```

We are utilizing a FilterablePageableDataProvider ([source code](https://github.com/Artur-/spring-data-provider/blob/master/src/main/java/org/vaadin/artur/spring/dataprovider/FilterablePageableDataProvider.java)) to load data from the backend. The important methods are:

```java
dataProvider = new FilterablePageableDataProvider<Type, Object> {
            @Override
            protected Stream<Type> fetchFromBackEnd(Query<Type, Object> query) {            
                return typeService.fetchFromBackEnd(query);
            }

            @Override
            protected int sizeInBackEnd(Query<Type, Object> query) {
                return typeService.sizeInBackEnd(query);
            }

            @Override
            protected List<QuerySortOrder> getDefaultSortOrders() {
                return Sort.asc("name").build();
            }
};
```

Including the following code to place it inside of a `Grid<Type>` 's column works fine, and sorting is no issue:

```java
grid.addColumn(type -> type.getName()).setSortProperty("name");
grid.addColumn(type -> type.getCallCode()).setSortProperty("callCode");
```

## Problem

What's giving me fits is trying to figure out how to have a column sort when using the grid item as a parameter in a query, such as:

```java
grid.addColumn(type -> eventService.countByType(type));
```

Using `setSortProperty(String ... properties)` no longer works, and using a Comparator is out of the question because there's too much data to do in-memory sorting.

How do I make this query sortable in my grid?

Comment: Projections are a good fit for this problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261090/spring-data-rest-how-to-include-calculated-data-in-a-projection. I'm working through a similar problem, but I need to additionally filter the eventService call by startDate and endDate. I'm noodling through how to add that to the projection.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Define a class EventFilter that has various attributes, alongwith getters/setters, that you need your records to be filtered on.
> 2. Pass an instance of this EventFilter to the DataProvider instance.
> 3. The DataProvider instance uses the attributes of the EventFilter instance to fetch the required records. The DataProvider instance has
>      the logic to extract the "sort" property from Query object and fetch the records
>      accordingly. See code below.

```
public class EventDataProvider extends AbstractBackEndDataProvider<Event, Void> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Logic logic = new Logic();
    private final EventFilter filter;

    public EventDataProvider(EventFilter filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    @Override
    protected Stream<Event> fetchFromBackEnd(Query<Event, Void> query) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SortingInfo sortingInfo = null;
        if (query.getSortOrders() != null && !query.getSortOrders().isEmpty()) {
            QuerySortOrder sortOrder = query.getSortOrders().get(query.getSortOrders().size() - 1);
            sortingInfo = new SortingInfo(sortOrder.getSorted(), sortOrder.getDirection());
        } else {
            sortingInfo = new SortingInfo("date", SortDirection.DESCENDING);
        }
        return logic.getEvents(messages, filter, query.getLimit(), query.getOffset(), sortingInfo).stream();
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeInBackEnd(Query<Event, Void> query) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return logic.getEventsCount(messages, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getId(Event item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return item.getDate() + "-" + item.getSlotId() + "-" + item.getLocationId();
    }
}
```